# Unity ParrelSync giving errors when trying to create clone and failing to open new clone

Tags: unity-game-engine, syntax-error, multiplayer

Whenever I try to create a clone of my project using ParrelSync, I get two errors:[image] [image]

In addition, whenever I try to open one of the cloned projects, a new unity window is created, as expected, but it does not respond, and instead opens up unity hub, before quitting the new unity window.

Ive looked at similar issues, but I haven't seen anything like this anywhere else, so I figured I would ask here. Any help would be appreciated!